# install/uninstall an .inf driver programmatically using C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, installation, driver

I am making an application using c#.net. It contains a filesystem minifilter driver also. I want to install and uninstall this driver programmatically using c# .net. Normally i can install this using the .INF file (by right click + press install).but I want to install this programmatically. There is an SDK function InstallHinfSection() for installing the .inf driver . I am looking for a .net equivalent for this function.

Regards

Navaneeth

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("Setupapi.dll", EntryPoint="InstallHinfSection", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void InstallHinfSection(
    [In] IntPtr hwnd,
    [In] IntPtr ModuleHandle,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string CmdLineBuffer,
    int nCmdShow);
```

Then to call it:

```
InstallHinfSection(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "my path", 0);
```

I generated most of this signature using the [P/Invoke Signature Generator](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2008/01/12/p-invoke-signature-generator.aspx).

The full details of this method and its parameters are on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376957(VS.85).aspx). According to MSDN the first parameter can be null, the second one *must* be null, and the last parameter *must* be 0. You only have to pass in the string parameter.

Comment: I was looking for a .net equivalent for this native API.

Comment: There isn't one. You have to P/Invoke it.

Comment: I should clarify: The .NET Framework does not include a managed code version of this API. The .NET Framework has very few APIs that wrap low-level Win32 APIs such as driver installation APIs. By declaring a P/Invoke method you're directly calling the native Win32 API from managed code.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, for some reason... (windows 10, x64, visual studio 2015) - doesn't give an error or nothing, just doesn't really install the inf file...

Comment: On windows 10, you need to add `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` to the `DllImport()` call

Comment: @JamieCockburn How do I add it to the call? I tried the same statement but I get "identifier expected" for the = symbol

Comment: @Macindows put that inside the `DllImport()` like this: `[DllImport(......., CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]`. You can look up "C# attribute syntax" to find more about this syntax.

Answer (score 7):

This simple code worked for me

```
    private void driverInstall()
    {

        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c C:\\Windows\\System32\\InfDefaultInstall.exe " + driverPath; // where driverPath is path of .inf file
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Dispose();
        MessageBox.Show(@"Driver has been installed");
    }
```

Comment: Works perfect from a console app. Although, i can't get it to run from a Windows Service running as SYSTEM. (win service is x86, the driver itself is x64, not sure if that matters).

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an error. The parameter is incorrect. This appears as a message box when I click on yes to the INF install UAC dialog. The INF file installs perfectly fine via the right click>Install method.

Comment: `driverPath` should be `"\"" + driverPath + "\""` to count for the INF file having any spaces in it.

Answer (score 2):

Same as @Ravians answer only I've added an `ExitCode` to check if the user has pressed yes or no to the dialog. `0` been that they pressed yes and `1` for no.

It also fixes the issue for the file path of the inf file when it has spaces.

```
public static readonly string windowsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows);
public static bool driversInstalledSuccessfully;
public static readonly string driverPath = @"C:/Path to/Driver.inf";

private static void DriverInstall(string driverFile)
{

    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + windowsPath + "\\System32\\InfDefaultInstall.exe " + "\"" + driverPath + "\""; // where driverPath is path of .inf file
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();

    if (process.ExitCode == 0)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Successfully Installed");
        driversInstalledSuccessfully = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Big Problemo");
        driversInstalledSuccessfully = false;
    }
    process.Dispose();

} // End DriverInstall
```

Called via

```
DriverInstall(driverPath);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for me, thanx!
Any idea on how to UNinstall a driver in the same way?

Comment: No problem. You have to ask a new question for that. I'm sure there's a few on here that deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

//public static readonly string windowsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows);
//public static bool driversInstalledSuccessfully;
//public static readonly string driverPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "Driver\64bit\u4.inf";

```
    private static void DriverInstall(string driverFile)
    {

        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c C:\\Windows\\System32\\InfDefaultInstall.exe " + driverPath + "\""; // where driverPath is path of .inf file
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        if (process.ExitCode == 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Successfully Installed");
            driversInstalledSuccessfully = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Big Problemo");
            driversInstalledSuccessfully = false;
        }
        process.Dispose();

    }
```

//it gave error the parameter is incorrect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).