# Adding .inf drivers using PowerShell, possible?

Tags: powershell, drivers

Are we able to install drivers via their .inf files etc. using a PowerShell cmdlet? When Googling I found, Add-WindowsDriver but I think this one is for an offline Windows image. Does that mean an image that is not currently used on an OS? If not, please teach me how to write the parameters. Thank you!

Comment: `Start-Process -Path $PathToInf -Verb Install`?

Comment: I just realize you can right click install .inf files, however, this .inf file says "The INF file you selected does not support this method of installation."

Comment: How about using PNPUTIL? For example: `pnputil.exe -i -a C:\example\example.INF`

Comment: Hi Benh, it gave me an error `Failed to install: No more data is available` I believe this is because the device already has an existing driver, I need to install these new drivers I have, how would I tell PS or CMD specifically to replace the existing drivers with this new one?

Comment: You'll need to delete the old one first. So you'll need to enumerate all of the current drivers with `pnputil.exe -e` then find what it's named and then  `pnputil.exe -f -d oem0.inf` (-f is force and may not be needed)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This PowerShell script will do what you want:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Driver File Location" -Recurse -Filter "*inf" | ForEach-Object { PNPUtil.exe /add-driver $_.FullName /install }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Powershell or advanced CMD programming, because `pnputil.exe` has a `/subdirs` command line switch and can slurp multiple `.inf` files at once. On my system (Windows 10 x64 21H2), you can simply execute:

```
pnputil /add-driver *.inf /install /subdirs
```

That does what I would expect.

`pnputil.exe`'s help tells everything we need. Just execute `pnputil` without further parameters, and it outputs an understandable help screen (that is too long to post it here).

Answer (score 0):

Reposting the comment (credit to @Bacon Bits), because it works.

```
Start-Process -$PathToInf -Verb Install
```

worked for me

Answer (score -1):

It can be done using the `Install-DeviceDriver` cmdlet from the [DeviceManagement module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/DeviceManagement/1.3.0). See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63567423/266876) for an example.

Comment: This tool is no longer working properly.